# Is there a Spanish idiom equivalent to "To put a bug in your ear"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-modismo

The idiom "Put a bug in your ear" means

- give somebody a reminder or suggestion relating to a future event
- to tell someone something that suggests what they should do <sub>([macmillandictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/put-a-bug-in-someone-s-ear))</sub>

> I put a bug in his ear about giving Helen a call.

- Give someone a hint about something <sub>([thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+bug+in+someone%27s+ear))</sub>

> Janet put a bug in her husband's ear about getting the children a dog for Christmas.

In all cases the buzzing of an insect would work as a analogy for having a reminder, hint, advice or appraise to do something in the future.

The direct translation into Spanish (`Voy a poner un bicho/insecto en tu oído`) does not work as an equivalent. Is there a Spanish equivalent idiom with the meaning of "hey, don't forget about this".

Comment: Tal y como lo planteas parece que sería "decir algo con indirectas" o "soltar una indirecta", ¿puede ser?

Comment: Te voy a dar un tip.

Comment: @Charlie, no, el modismo hace una referencia muy directa tipo "oye, que no se te olvide que...". No es a malas tampoco. Es algo así como "Como recordatorio, esto o lo otro" o "Te recuerdo que los niños quieren un perro por navidad". No sé si hay un modismo o expresión (o incluso un verbo que no sea "recordar") que se pueda usar en esta situación.

Comment: O bien, *te doy un tip.*

Answer (score 3):

Creo que he dado con una expresión que podría servir, a ver qué te parece. En español existe la siguiente palabra:

> **[runrún](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WqbbnhX)**
>
> Tb. **rum rum** en aceps. 1-3, p. us.
>   Voz onomat.
>
> 1. m. Zumbido, ruido o sonido continuado y bronco.
> 2. m. Ruido confuso de voces.
> 3. m. coloq. Voz que corre entre el público.

Esta palabra se puede usar de forma figurada en frases que implican que el *runrún* es una voz, ruido o zumbido que oyes en tu cabeza, como en el siguiente ejemplo (negritas mías):

> *No podía no hablarse de la guerra. Isabel se daba cuenta de eso. Zamacois tenía siempre la guerra en la cabeza **como un runrún**: los fusilamientos.*
>
> Álvaro Pombo, "Una ventana al norte", 2004 (España).

Por tanto, tu ejemplo se podría expresar en español con este modismo de la siguiente forma:

> Janet le recordó a su marido lo de regalarles un perro a los niños para Navidad, a ver si se le quedaba ahí el runrún.

Comment: pero en este caso, runrún es la idea que le queda al marido después de que la mujer le ha recordado algo, no la acción de recordárselo en si.

Comment: @BrianH. por supuesto. Estoy buscando una expresión en español lo más parecida posible, o que al menos dé la misma idea. Tampoco se trata de hacer una equivalencia al 100%. Lo del _runrún_ equivaldría a la parte de "the buzzing of an insect", que fue lo que me dio la idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "**apuntarse (algo) en la cabeza**" would be a valid translation. For example:

> I put a bug in his ear about giving Helen a call.

could be translated to:

> Le dije que se apuntara (bien) en la cabeza (el / lo de) llamar a Helen.

I've heard too "**métete bien esto en tu cabeza**", but I find it a little bit aggresive. It's like you have to interiorize the sentence as a must, or forever:

> Le dije que se metiera bien en la cabeza que tiene que llamar a Helen.
>
> ¡Métete bien en la cabeza que tienes que llamar a Helen!

You can also use "que no se te pase". Where "pasar" is used with the meaning of "olvidar" like these:

> Que no se te pase llamar a Helen.
>
> Que no se te olvide llamar a Helen.

Answer (score 2):

I think one can use the idea explained [here](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/1561069754):

> "Put a bug in someone's ear" means to subtly plant an idea in someone's head, an idea that you hope he will think about.

To say:

> Plantar/implantar una idea

Maybe also:

> Insinuar una idea

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina utilizamos la siguientes frases:

> ¡Que se te grabe en la cabeza!
>
> ¡Que se te incruste en la cabeza!